# How to update Subversion Edge's Apache HTTP Server to the newest version?

Tags: apache, svn, subversion-edge

How to update Subversion Edge's Apache Server to newest version? Is this possible? I am running the latest version of Subversion Edge (Release: 5.0.1) But my Apache HTTP Server version is 2.4.12

[image]

How can I upgrade it to 2.4.16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but as far as I understand you should wait till newer Subversion Edge version linked against newer HTTPd gets released. In other words, you can't (and shouldn't) upgrade Subversion Edge components manually.